# Second Monitor not Detected, Ubutnu 22.04, AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, radeon

I am trying to install an AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT GPU in Ubuntu 22.04. I went through the amdgpu install process, however only one monitor (connected to the motherboard) is detected. The monitor which is connected to the GPU isn't detected. I am fairly new to Linux. Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Outputs:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' 
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 52) DeviceName: ASPEED Video AST2600 Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc ASPEED Graphics Family Kernel driver in use: ast
43:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] (rev c1) Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] Kernel driver in use: amdgpu Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

```
$ xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 1 0: +*VGA-1 1920/531x1080/299+0+0 VGA-1
```

[image: Screenshot showing Graphics as llvmpipe in Settings -> About]